# Determine the close button click of Browser, refresh and going to new page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have to clear session and delete some data from my database on browser close/refresh/location change

i need a code which could do something like this

```
$('cross button,refresh').click(function()
{
    preventdefault();
    // call my delete script
    $(browser).close();
});
```

Comment: You are missing your brackets after your function: it should be `function ()`

Comment: @NatZimmermann thanks but thats not the point here... i just gave a dummy code.... i need the actual code to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
  // Your code here
});
```

This will trigger when the user tries to leave the page.